# During an AppScan, is it possible to tell if a specific URL has been scanned?

Tags: security, dynamic, penetration-testing, security-testing

I'm using IBM AppScan Standard. When I run a scan, in the left hand pane with the 'URL Based' button selected, I can see the different URLs that AppScan has found and will be scanned. While the scan is in progress I know that at the bottom of the window you can see the current URL that is being tested but is there any other way to tell if a certain URL has been fully scanned yet?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the final report. In Appscan to be certain whether each URL is visited by the tool is through the final report generated by the tool.

While generating the report in Appscan you have to select the appropriate `check-boxes` displayed on the Right-Side of the `Create Report` popup window.

I usually select all the `check-boxes` displayed under the section `Application Data`.

You can get to know `Visited URLs, Failed Requests, Filtered URLs, Cookies, etc` using this option in the final report.

This is very helpful in my project where we have to pass the security audit. Audit Team in my project checks each and every security report and can be convinced easily if they see all the visited URLs in our final report.